# Zero determinant for a 12×12 matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

[image]

I know the determinant of this matrix is zero. Can someone explain how to obtain it?

Comment: Try rearranging rows and columns. If any two rows or columns are same , then determinant is 0

Answer (score 5):

Step 1 :

Divide $C_5$ with 2.

Step 2 :

Since $C_5$ and $C_{11}$ are same, determinant of given matrix is 0.

[Why determinant is zero when two rows or columns are same?](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Square_Matrix_with_Duplicate_Rows_has_Zero_Determinant)